# I'm trying to make a proxy scraper python

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to play around and make a simple scraper proxy as a newbie to python.

I can't get what I want in the end as a result!

Why only one proxy appears in the result?

> `79.110.200.27:8000` `Totol Proxies: 599`

If I set `print()` like this I get them all!!!

```
    if Pmatch:
        prox = Pmatch.group()
        print(prox)
```

But, I want them all 599 proxies to come out one by one in the `return prox`

What am I doing wrong here?!

```
import re
import http.client as res
ppattern = '((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})'

def proxyscrape():
    payload = ''
    headers = {}
    try:
        conn = res.HTTPSConnection("api.proxyscrape.com")
        conn.request("GET", "/v2/?request=displayproxies&protocol=http&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=elite", payload, headers)
        data = conn.getresponse().read()
        P1list = data.decode("utf-8")
    except:
        P1list = ""
    try:
        conn = res.HTTPSConnection("raw.githubusercontent.com")
        conn.request("GET", "/zloi-user/hideip.me/main/http.txt", payload, headers)
        data = conn.getresponse().read()
        P2list = data.decode("utf-8")
    except:
        P2list = ""
    proxylist = str(P1list+P2list)
    lines = proxylist.split('\n')
    totLen = str(len(lines))
    totLen = 'Totol Proxies: '+totLen
    for proxy in lines:
        Pmatch = re.search(ppattern,proxy,re.IGNORECASE)
        if Pmatch:
            prox = Pmatch.group()
        return prox+'\n'+totLen

Proxy_Scraper=proxyscrape()
print(Proxy_Scraper)
```

Comment: A function only returns once. In other words, the very first time that the code reaches a `return` it returns and the function execution is finished. Instead you likely want to store your `prox+'\n'+totlen`, in each iteration of your for loop, in a list. And then once the loop is complete, `return yourlist`.